# (Python) Why am I getting a syntax error on my variable?

Tags: python, variables, syntax

[image]

For some reason I'm getting a syntax error on my variable name (line 16)

Comment: Please don't submit your code as an image, it's harder for people to read and will maybe disappear someday. SO questions are meant to be useful for anyone running into the same issue, so future proofing is nice :)

Answer (score 1):

On line 14 you forgot a closing parenthesis `)` at the end of the line.

```
number_per_year = int(input("Number of interest compounds per year:" )) # Add a bracket here
```